# upload and show image in browser

Tags: smartgwt

Does anyone know how I can make a user interface using smartgwt where the person uploads an image and the image is displayed on the screen?

I tried UploadItem but it only shows brows button using which we can go into the location of image file but i want also to show uploaded image on the screen

Is it possible in smartgwt?